# Changing dialog appearance (labels, etc) of tool made in ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, modelbuilder

For this tool I've created, I would like to change how the user would see the things they can choose. This is the tool in ModelBuilder:

[image]

And this is what the user sees when they click on the tool:

[image]

I would like to change what the user sees so that:

1. The label that currently says CSRS_ORN_NER would say Selecting Features.
2. The label that currently says Stations_Diff_by_CSRS would say Input Layer.
3. The Field option is no longer there.
4. The Linear unit can only be in kilometers, meters, or miles.
5. The fields are all blank when the tool is opened.
6. This fields are ordered in this way: Selecting Features, Input Layer, Selection Type, Distance.
7. And lastly, you can bypass clicking the 'browse for a folder' button next to two of the fields and just click the drop-down arrow to search for your input.

Answer (score 2):

To rename a parameter name, rename the element in the model itself.

Next, the 'linear' option will always be there as long as you expose the distance parameter from the buffer tool.

A workaround would be to create another variable of 'Double' type and call it "Distance"

Then connect that variable to the Buffer tool and assign it to the "Distance [value or field]" parameter.

Mark the Distance variable as a parameter (right-click > Model Parameter), along with your other parameters.

Now when you run the tool, the user only has the option to type in the number of units (in this case feet) you want them to buffer by:

[image]

(Remember you can re-order parameters in the options menu under Model > Model Properties > Parameters settings.

Lastly: you can't get rid of that 'browse' button...